# (2004 Lincoln Navigator) How do I fix the side of the drivers seat?

Tags: ford, seat, lincoln, navigator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1cJW.jpg

All the buttons work I just don’t know how to get this thing back into place. My mom said the truck was broken into and they damaged the seat in the process.

Edit: If it needs to be replaced then what is the part called exactly and where do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is referred to as  Driver Side Front Seat Trim Panel Shield Left Hand. A simple search (2004 Lincoln Navigator lower seat trim) for this resulted in several suppliers. My guess is that it snaps into place and the tabs are broken. It is available in several colors some more expensive then others. You can choose your priority cost or appearance.